# highlight strings red

Tags: c#

As simple as it is, I cannot get it to work. The goal is to highlight strings red in csharp code.

```
private void HighlightStrings() 
{
  Regex regex = new Regex(@"^""*""$", RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);
  MatchCollection MC = regex.Matches(this.Text);

  foreach (Match match in MC)
  {
    this.Select(match.Index, match.Length);
    this.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
  }
}
```

Comment: What is _"not working"_? Show what you expect to happen, what happens and what you have tried.

Comment: What are `this.Text`, `this.Select` and `this.SelectionColor` ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to match any number of consecutive double quotes?  That is what your regex matches.  Well, you actually are matching any line that has only double quotes on it.  Maybe you meant your regex to be the following:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@""".*""", RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);
```

This would match any double quoted string anywhere on the line.